# Hp 14-dk0xxx BIOS update, but just how?

Tags: boot, bios, usb-flash-drive, efi, hp-pavilion

I have this 14-dk0xxx notebook where I have installed Ubuntu 22 LTS.

I just wanted to update the bios but it seems a mess.

Ok I have no Windows like the other 90% of the users do, so I dowloaded the .exe file (thank you HP guys where a f*****g zip would have sufficied) and ran it on a Windows machine.

Then I created a usb flash and used the utility to create an "official bios disk"

Annoying but until here all ok.

Now:

- this machine hasn't a voice into the menu for update the bios
- someone says that pressing f2 would have contained an option for the BIOS update, sadly my machine hasn't it, it only have disk and memory check.
- pressing win+b would call the emergency recover screen, doing it without flash says that theres'nt a drive, but if I do it when the flash is inserted just skips silently this screen and boot the os
- the pendrive itself isn't bootable it has only EFI,HP and Helwett Packard folders

TL;DR: how I am supposed to use this flash drive?

Is my only one option format the machine to a Windows os just for run the executable directly updating from windows without using the flash drive?

to me sounds crazy

the very hp flash drive built by their unpacker doesn't works on their pc :/

can some of you with a lot of patience try to help me? their support is not helping

I miss the business series where you can update the bios via network.

Comment: I do not know about HP but Lenovo offers a bootable CD for updating BIOS.  This should be operating system agnostic.  I am not certain because I use Windows.  Look for a comparable CD from HP.

Comment: Switch off Secure Boot if it’s enabled. You _are_ attempting to UEFI boot this drive, right?

Answer (score 2):

Before I'd install Windows on the PC, I'd use that executable while *booted from Windows on USB*. This is faster and safer than making changes to the main drive.

- Use [Win PE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-create-usb-bootable-drive?view=windows-11) or [WinRE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-recovery-environment--windows-re--technical-reference?view=windows-11). Not only can you "bake boot media from scratch," but you can create a prebuilt environment from various tools, such as [Hiren’s BootCD PE](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/), from [AOMEI](https://www.diskpart.com/windows-10/winpe-bootable-disk-windows-10-5740.html), [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/manual/create-winpe-bootable-disk-for-diskgenius.php) or [Macrium](https://www.macrium.com/blog/the-macrium-rescue-environment-cca57a4ebc61).

  It is possible the HP executable might run from only a specific version of Win PE or WinRE, so if one attempt fails, another might succeed.
- Make an (almost) complete Windows 10 boot USB, such as Hasleo's [WinToUSB](https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/index.html) or an [alternative](https://www.easeus.com/system-to-go/best-windows-to-go-creator-software.html). My experience running a full Win 10 instance from USB has not been positive.

  - It takes **far** longer to build the bootable media than to create a useful PE environment, as from *Hiren’s BootCD PE*.
  - It takes **far** longer to boot from USB -- even with high-speed media, boot may take more than 1/2 hour.
  - Running from USB is **far** slower, because writing to files *required* by Windows 10, such as the Registry files, swapfile.sys and and pagefile.sys is *very* slow in flash memory. [Win PE and RE are small enough to be kept in RAM.]

**N.B.**

- Before making *any* major change to the PC, make a complete drive image to allow recovery.
- Be sure that BIOS update is not interrupted -- a bad update can permanently make the PC useless, *beyond recovery*.

Comment: Isn't use a winpe environment riskier than use win10 full? I can install a working version of the win os in 10 minutes and then restore linux easily after.

Comment: @user3450548, yes, you can do a full Win 10 install -- but it's not perfect. Answer will be amended.

Answer (score -1):

At the end I gave up and installed win10 temporarly. This could be achived also by removing the main drive installing it on an empty drive and by putting it back after.

I also used the flash drive for moving it on the original hp exe file, so I ran the UPDATE step from the machine itself.
(and also avoiding connecting the new windows machine to internet at all, avoiding unstable drivers and so on...)

What happens if you choose update directly, it doesn't do it inside Windows as I tough and was scared of some Windows services can interfere.

It reboots instead and loads at startup the hp flashing environment that do a complex procedure of flashing multiple bios sections.

To me go for bartpe is not doable, too risky because I can't tell if all the subsequent booting part would be run correctly.

For the load at starup alternative would be nice have one however theresn't a specific update bios section, but only the capability of run an efi file and who knows how to do properly flashing all the parts and not only one leaving an uncertain state.

TL;DR: this may be one of the longest way but to me the safest, best if you have a spare drive to install Windows on it or use acronis or similar software for backup and restore the original linux os.